# find the inverse matrix in finite difference method

Tags: matrices, inverse, finite-differences

my matrix derived in the finite difference method is like this, how can I find the inverse of it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BwfR.png)

Comment: Please add some works you have done/ideas you have tried. Just asking to solve a question isn't well-recieved.

Comment: Why would you want to do that as part of a numerical method solution process? If your goal is to solve $Ax=b$ then finding the inverse of $A$ is not efficient